# How to integrate the following functions?

Tags: calculus

I have a hard time fully solving the following functions. I'm just beginning with partial and substitution methods so if you could show me how to proceed, that would be great.

This is where I am with the following functions:

**First problem:**

$$f(x)= \frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8}$$
$$\int\frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8} dx$$
$$\int \frac{x+2}{U}dx$$

---

$$U=x^2-4x+8$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}= 2x-4$$
$$dx = \frac{1}{2x-4} du$$

---

$$\int \frac{x+2}{U}\frac{1}{2(x-2)}du$$
From here on I have no idea how to solve it. The $x$'s don't cancel.

**Second problem:**
$$\int 3x^2sin(x^3)\,\,dx$$

---

$$U=3x^2$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=6x$$
$$du=6x\,\,dx$$
$$dv=sin(x^3)dx$$
$$v=\int sin(x^3) dx$$
Now another substitution (?):
$$v= \int sin(x^3) dx$$
$$u=x^3$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2$$
$$dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du$$
$$\int sin(u)\frac{1}{3x^2}\,\,du$$

---

So I guess you have a pretty good idea of where this is going.. Does the second problem need another partial integration? I don't see an end in sight.

All help is appreciated,

-Bowser

Comment: @cataline thought when you used integration by parts you set the 'destructive' thing equal to u and the 'non-destructive' thing to dv?

Comment: For the second question, the $3x^2$ in the numerator and denominator should cancel leaving $\sin^3(u)$. You forgot to include the $3x^2$ in the numerator from the beginning.

Comment: First problem :Write numerator as $0.5(2x-4)+4$ to begin with. Why would I create the denom's derivative in the numerator???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, I'd separate the integral into two integrals
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\int\frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8}dx =\int\frac{x-2}{x^2-4x+8}dx +\int\frac{4}{x^2-4x+8}dx
\end{equation}
The first integral is easy to solve through variable substitution
\begin{equation}
U = x^2-4x+8,\quad (dU = 2x-4)dx, \quad \frac{1}{2}dU = (x-2)dx
\end{equation}
The first integral becomes:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{U}dU = \frac{1}{2}\ln{U}+C_1 = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\left|x^2-4x-8 \right|}+C_1
\end{equation}

The second integral can be done by completing the square in the denominator. Note:
\begin{equation}
x^2-4x+8 = (x-2)^2+4
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{4}{x^2-4x+8}dx=4\int\frac{1}{(x-2)^2+4}dx
\end{equation}
I'll factor a 4 from the denominator (which will cancel with the four outside of the integral)
\begin{equation}
4\int\frac{1}{(x-2)^2+4}dx = \frac{4}{4}\int\frac{1}{ \frac{1}{4}(x-2)^2+1}dx\\
\int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right)^2+1}dx = \int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)^2+1}dx \\
\end{equation}
Another variable substitution can be done now
\begin{gather}
U = x/2-1,\quad dU = \frac{1}{2}dx\quad 2dU = dx
\end{gather}
The integral that results is
\begin{gather}
\int\frac{2}{U^2+1}dU
\end{gather}
Whose integral results in 
\begin{gather}
\int\frac{2}{U^2+1}dU = 2\tan^{-1}{\left(U\right)}+C_2\\
2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)+C_2
\end{gather}
Thus the total answer is (Note $C=C_1+C_2$):
\begin{gather}
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\left|x^2-4x+8 \right|}+2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)+C
\end{gather}

$\boldsymbol{Second}$ $\boldsymbol{Problem}$

The second problem requires a variable substitution of argument of the sine function. 
\begin{gather}
U = x^3\quad dU = 3x^2dx\\
\int 3x^2\sin{(x^3)}dx = \int \sin{(U)}du
\end{gather}
You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: I managed to solve the second one with your help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+8}=\frac{2x-4}{x^2-4x+8}+\frac{6}{x^2-4x+8}$$ in 
$$\int x^2\sin(x^3) dx$$ we have $$x^3=u$$ and $$3x^2dx=du$$

Comment: Isn't it $x-4 +6 $or am I missing something?

Comment: That sine function has no cube on it after u-sub...

Comment: Indeed it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

for the first integral write the numerator as
$$
x+2=\frac{1}{2}(2x-4)+4
$$
so that you can divide the integral in a sum and you have the derivative of the denominator at the numerator.

For the second note that:

$$\int 3x^2sin(x^3)\,\,dx=\int sin(x^3) d(x^3)$$